# how to display standard fields of custom object in visual force

Tags: visualforce

hi I created a custom object county. at the time of creation i created record name field as a text and name it as countryname when i display it on visualforce page using this following expression {!country__c.countryname} i am getting error how to display it

Comment: This seems like a too basic question.

Comment: Shouldn't that be {!country__c.countryname__c} ?

Comment: <apex:outputField value="{!country__c.countryname__c}"/>
    
Thanks,
Pritam Shekhawat

Comment: hi bart juriewicz your saying that it's a basic question? do you know standard fields in custom objects won't have api names

Answer (score 1):

You are using Field Label. Instead use Field API Name like this:

```
<apex:inpuputField value="{!country__c.Name}"/>
```

Thanks,

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: You are using Field Label instead use Field API Name
<apex:outputField value="{!country.Name}"/>
Thanks,

Comment: hi thanks for your idea i had tried even i am getting error.standard fields in custom objects won't have api names